# When should I create a class for a Map key?

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm using Java 6.

Suppose I have a class which I would like to save its instances into a map. Later on I would like to retrieve instances using only the "key fields". I'll ignore field modifiers, getters, and setters for conciseness.

```
class A {

    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;
    String field4;
    //more fields

    public int hashCode(){
        //uses only field1 and field2
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        //uses only field1 and field2
    }
}
```

Since Java's standard API doesn't have the MultikeyMap and I don't want to use 3rd party libraries, I have a choice of
1) creating a new class `KeyA` to represent the key of a map
2) use `A` itself as the key and populate only the "key fields" when I need to retrieve objects from a map
3) nest the maps, e.g. `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, A>>`
4) other workarounds

What do people normally use and when?

Comment: You need to store the class or instances of that class? If you want store objects separate, you can use HashSet.

Comment: Instances of that class (edited the question). How do I retrieve an instance from a HashSet if I only have field1 and field2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your recent edit, you should be fine to use instances of class A as keys in this situation.  Lookups will be done based on the semantics of `equals()` and `hashCode()`, so this will cause instances to be retrieved by only the "key fields".  Hence the following code would work as you intend:

```
final Map<A, String> map = new HashMap<A, Object>();
final A first = new A("fe", "fi", "fo", "fum");

map.put(first, "success");

// later on
final A second = new A ("fe", "fi", "foo", "bar");
System.out.println(map.get(second)); // prints "success";
```

Having said that, your description of option 2 makes me a little concerned that this might not be the most sensible option.  If you create a `Map<A, String>`, that's a mapping from *instances of class A* to strings.  Yet your second point implies that you want to think of it as a mapping from *pairs of key fields* to strings.  If you're going to usually look up values based on a couple of "raw" strings, then I'd advise against this.  It feels wrong (to me), to create a "fake" instance of A just to do a lookup - so in this case, you probably should create a key class that embodies the pair of strings as described in option 1.  (You could even embed instances of these within your `A` objects to hold the key fields).

There's a similar argument for or against option 3, too.  If the strings really are conceptually hierarchical, then it might well make sense.  For example, if `field1` was Country, and `field2` was Town, one could definitely argue that the nested maps make sense - you have a mapping from country, to the map of Town->A relations within that country.  But if your keys don't naturally compose in this fashion (say, if they were (x, y) coordinates), this would again not be a very natural way to represent the data, and a single-level map from `XYPoint` to value would be more sensible.  (Likewise, if you *never* use the two-level map except to always go straight through both layers, one could argue the one-level map still makes more sense.)

And finally, as for option 4 -if you're **always** mapping to `A` itself, and storing the key as its own value (e.g. if you want to canonicalise your `A` instances, a bit like `String.intern()`) then as was pointed out you needn't use a `Map` at all, and a `Set` will do the job here.  The `Map` is useful when you want to establish relationships between *different* objects, whereas a `Set` automatically gives you the uniqueness of objects without any extra conceptual overhead.

---

If you do use the class itself as a key, be warned though that objects should only generally be used as keys if their `hashCode` (and the behaviour of `equals`) won't change over time.  Typically this means the keys are immutable, though here you could afford to have mutable "non-key" fields.  If you were to break this rule, you'd see odd behaviour such as the following:

```
// Populate a map, with an A as the key
final Map<A, String> map = new HashMap<A, Object>();
final A a = new A("one", "two", "three", "four");
map.put(a, "here");

// Mutate a
a.setField1("un");

// Now look up what we associated with it
System.out.println(map.get(a)); // prints "null" - huh?
System.out.println(map.containsKey(a)); // prints "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an `Index` class, something like this (warning: untested code), to abstract out the indexing functionality. Why Java doesn't have something like this already is puzzling to me.

```
interface Indexer<T, K> 
{
    /** extract key from index */
    public K getIndexKey(T object); 
}

class Index<T,K>
{
    final private HashMap<K,List<T>> indexMap = new HashMap<K,List<T>>();
    final private Indexer<T,K> indexer;

    public Index(Indexer<T,K> indexer)
    {
        this.indexer = indexer;
    }

    public void add(T object) {
        K key = this.indexer.getIndexKey(object);
        List<T> values = this.indexMap.get(key);
        if (values == null)
        {
            values = new ArrayList<T>();
            this.indexMap.put(key, values);
        }
        values.add(object);
    }
    public void remove(T object) {
        K key = this.indexer.getIndexKey(object);
        List<T> values = this.indexMap.get(key);
        if (values != null)
        {
            values.remove(object);
        }
    }
    public List<T> lookup(K key) {
        List<T> values = this.indexMap.get(key);
        return values == null 
           ? Collections.emptyList()
           : Collections.unmodifiableList(values);
    }
}
```

example relevant to your `class A`:

```
Index<A,String> index1 = new Index<A,String>(new Indexer<A,String>() {
    @Override public String getIndexKey(A object)
    {
        return object.field1;
    }
});    
Index<A,String> index2 = new Index<A,String>(new Indexer<A,String>() {
    @Override public String getIndexKey(A object)
    {
        return object.field2;
    }
});    
/* repeat for all desired fields */
```

You would manually have to add and remove entries from the indices, but all the grungework below those operations is handled by the Index class.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has "key fields". I would suggest to create a parent class, `ParentA`, with those key fields (which certainly map to a concept in your domain) and inherit this class in your child class `A`.

Override `hashCode()` and `equals()` in the `ParentA` class.

Use a `Map<ParentA, A>` to store your `A` instances and give the instance as key and value.

To retrieve a specific `A` instance, create a new `ParentA` instance, `pA`, with your key fields set, and do

```
A a = map.get(pA);
```

That's it.

Another way is to create a `AIdentifier` class with key fields and add an instance as `A` property `id`. So you add your instance with `map.put(a.id, a);` That's inheritance vs composition pattern discussion :)