# Use Map for complex key

Tags: java

Im a beginner in Java. I have the following method in java:

```
public void filter(Long time_start, Long time_stop){
     ArrayList<Long> time = new ArrayList<Long>();
     ArrayList<Integer> stream = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     ArrayList<Integer> cpuid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     ArrayList<Integer> token = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

I get an input from the user for the `time_start` and `time_stop`, that is passed to this method. The ArrayList time contains the value that is entered by the user (both `time_start` and `time_stop`). What I want to do is this: For every given start and end time...look through the time ArrayList and return the `time, stream, cpuid and token` starting from time_start until time_end. Each value in the time ArrayList is unique.

How do I do this? I know that there are Map interface in Java, but that can accept only one key as input. I want to look for a range of values and output all the fields corresponding to that range.

Can anybody tell me the right and best way to do this? The ArrayLists of time,cpuid,etc can be very big at times.

Comment: You cannot declare `static` variables in methods. Your code won't compile.

Comment: @fge Im sorry this is not the exact code...

Comment: Remove `static` , are you looking for `List<Map>` ?

Comment: How about a `Map` between `time`'s and an class containing your attributes? Think OO!

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388275/when-should-i-create-a-class-for-a-map-key

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup yes a Map is possible...but im looking for a range of values and not just one value in `time`. I think NavigableMap is the one im looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.util.NavigableMap`.  It has methods that allow retrieving ranges, near matches, and everything you need.

You should define a class to represent the tuple of the time, stream, cpuid, and token values for each event in one object, rather than using parallel lists.  I will be calling this class `Data` for now.

To get the entries with keys in the range from `time_start` to `time_stop`, you can just do this:

```
NavigableMap<Long,Data> myMap;

public NavigableMap filter(Long time_start, Long time_stop){
    return myMap.subMap(time_start, time_stop);
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer! I just have a silly doubt, how do I print out all the fields within that range returned by the myMap.submap? Or how do I access each field within that submap separately? Say I want to print only the cpuid for that range?

Comment: @user2358330 You can access it by iterating through the submap's entry set (I'd do it with an enhanced for-loop, but that's not the only way).  The type for the iterated variable is then `Map.Entry<Long,Data>`, which has key and value members that you can access with its getter methods.  You can then get at the cpuid by accessing the members of the entry's value, which is of your `Data` type.

Answer (score 3):

Use Java's excellent OO features and create something like

```
public class DataPoint {
   startTime;
   endTime;
   stream;
   cpuId;
   token;
}
```

and store that in your List. And yes, that won't compile, I leave the actual implementation to you.

Comment: I think the OP meant that each event has only one time value, and he wants to _retrieve_ the datapoints with values between the start and end.

Comment: @AJMansfield he could (in fact should) still use the same principle, except maybe use a Map<Date,DataPoint> for storage (even though that gives some data replication, it might be faster for retrieval based on timestamp than iterating through a List and querying a member of the retrieved instance).